# Is it possible to route all admin db reads to a slave DB?

Tags: database, django, admin, routes

In Django is it possible to create a MultiDB Router to make admin pages to read from different DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this snippet:
http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2037/
Changing below method should work:

```
def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
    # Check the path if it is admin
    if "/admin/" in request.path:
        request_cfg.cfg = "admin_database_name"
```